# How can I maintain an empty Java EE Enterprise Application project in Netbeans with users?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, prototype, new-project

I have created a basic Java EE project in Netbeans with some standard features that I use in every project.
I.e.

- I have used  a mysql database with some basic tables for users and groups.
- I have used JAAS security and created new realm.
- I have made a new persistence unit on this db
- I have created some basic beans for the login
- I have added primefaces as jsf lib
- I have created some basic menu and a basic form for manage users.

All these features above are needed for every project that I do and I trying to find a way to skip redoing it all these from scratch.

I have tried 2 ways. The first was to copy all project directory and trying to rename only the changes. I must confess that it was a disaster.
The other try was to create a new project an try to copy things from one project to another.

I am seeking for a solution that will make me have a project with the above minimum functionality and I should only change the database connection and project name.

Comment: Have you tried [this tutorial](http://netbeans.dzone.com/tips/hack-your-own-custom-project-t)?

Comment: I think perissf's way solves my problem. Will have to try it out though first.

Answer (score 2):

Maven archetypes may provide a solution.  They provide a starting point for projects.  Just started using them myself to build projects in Eclipse.  You can create your own archetypes to be used within your team.  A couple of references below:

[guide-creating-archetypes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html)

[creating-maven-web-application](http://javaevangelist.blogspot.com/2011/07/creating-maven-web-application.html)